# Gulp Browserify takes longer to compile on each save/change

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, browserify

I'm trying to speed up my Gulp workflow, using Browserify. I'm following this blog post:
http://christianalfoni.github.io/javascript/2014/08/15/react-js-workflow.html

I have everything working, and changes are initially quite quick (500ms or so).

However, this time increases each time I save a file. My task:

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {

var bundler = browserify({
    entries: ['./src/js/app.js'],
    debug: production,
    cache: {},
    packageCache: {},
    fullPaths: true
});

var watcher = watchify(bundler);

return watcher
    .on('update', function() {

        var updateStart = Date.now();

        function transform(next) {
          console.log('JavaScript changed - recomiling via Browserify');
          watcher.transform(babelify).bundle()
          .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/scripts'))
          .on('end', next);
        }

        transform(function() {
          gulp.start('usemin');
          console.log('Complete!', (Date.now() - updateStart) + 'ms');
        });

    })
    .transform(babelify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/scripts'));
```

So on first build, it takes around 3 seconds (and that's including one file).

Then, on file change:

```
JavaScript changed - recomiling via Browserify
[11:31:24] Starting 'usemin'...
Complete! 608ms
[11:31:24] Finished 'usemin' after 24 ms
JavaScript changed - recomiling via Browserify
[11:31:29] Starting 'usemin'...
Complete! 785ms
[11:31:29] Finished 'usemin' after 26 ms
JavaScript changed - recomiling via Browserify
[11:31:31] Starting 'usemin'...
Complete! 814ms
[11:31:31] Finished 'usemin' after 17 ms
JavaScript changed - recomiling via Browserify
[11:31:33] Starting 'usemin'...
Complete! 1112ms
[11:31:33] Finished 'usemin' after 17 ms
JavaScript changed - recomiling via Browserify
[11:31:36] Starting 'usemin'...
Complete! 1594ms
[11:31:36] Finished 'usemin' after 16 ms
```

I'm not actually changing the file, just saving it over and over. Is something stacking up here which I'm missing?

EDIT:

It turns out removing `.transform(babelify)` from the 'update' removes this issue. Not sure what issues this might cause down the line though... or why that makes it take ages.

Comment: Try `watchify` (https://github.com/substack/watchify) for incremental changes on saving. It should be a lot faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is something stacking up here which I'm missing?
>
> ...
>
> It turns out removing `.transform(babelify)` from the 'update' removes this issue. Not sure what issues this might cause down the line though... or why that makes it take ages.

Yes, by calling `.transform()` in the `update` handler it is "stacking up" by adding multiple passes of the transform. So each time it bundles, babelify is processing the bundled files `n` times. See [substack/watchify#187](https://github.com/substack/watchify/issues/187), particularly @zertosh's comments. Your script should be more like this:

```js
gulp.task('browserify', function () {
  var watcher = watchify(
    browserify({
      entries: ['./src/js/app.js'],
      debug: production,
      cache: {},
      packageCache: {},
      // FYI, this is no longer required in recent versions
      // of watchify, in case that's why you're using it.
      // See https://github.com/substack/watchify/pull/160
      fullPaths: true
    })
      .transform(babelify)
   );

  function bundle () {
    return watcher
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/scripts'));
  }

  function update () {
    var updateStart = Date.now();

    console.log('JavaScript changed - recomiling via Browserify');

    bundle()
      .on('end', function () {
        gulp.start('usemin');
        console.log('Complete!', (Date.now() - updateStart) + 'ms');
      });
  }

  watcher.on('update', update);

  return bundle();
});
```